# How to download demographics data with Facebook Analytics for Apps?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-analytics

"Facebook Analytics for Apps" documentation provides an API to export our data: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/analytics/export#faqs

They say "we don't support exporting demographic data at the device level".

I want to download my demographic data (gender, age) at a global level (no need for device one) but I found no way to get it with the API.

It is possible to download a CSV next to the charts they are displaying: did someone manage to get it programatically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get aggregated demographics such as age,gender,language,country for events via the App Insights API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application/app_insights/.